# Excel 2013: Find a string, replace value in adjacent column, across workbook

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a workbook with several hundred sheets. For all instances where `Clear Votive Cup` appears in **column B**, I need to change the value of **column H** in the same row (from `2.49` to `1.49`). This needs to apply to all worksheets.

The columns are consistently **B** and **H**, but the rows vary. I cannot use Find-Replace because there are other values of `2.49` that need to stay `2.49`. Can I create an `If-Then` statement that searches the entire workbook?

Answer (score 0):

This simple program will do the trick. This contains two loops:

> **For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets**
>
> > This is somewhat self-explanatory. This will loop through each worksheet in your workbook that contains this code.

Within the above loop contains another "sub loop":

> **For r = 2 To lastRow(ws, "B")**
>
> > So, we already know from the previous loop that `ws` is the current worksheet in the "parent loop". r = 2 is the starting row (you can change this to r = 1 if you do NOT have any column headers). `lastRow` is a function I included in the below code to automatically determine the last row in any column (in your case we are using column 2 / column B).

**The following code has been tested and works:**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub changeRows()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        For r = 2 To lastRow(ws, "B")
            If ws.Cells(r, 2) = "Clear Votive Cup" Then
                ws.Cells(r, "H") = 1.49
            End If
        Next r
    Next ws

End Sub

Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Variant = 1) As Long
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
    End With
End Function
```